# How do I transfer my blog posts from Google's Blogger to WordPress?

Tags: blogger, wordpress, migrate-data

I have a blog on Google's Blogger, but now I want to move to WordPress.

Is there an easy way to transfer all my old blog posts from Blogger to WordPress?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using Wordpress 3.0 so I am not sure if this applies to previous versions of WP or not.

In the WP admin, go to Tools > Import. Then you'll see a list of import tools you can install and use.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress admin go to Tools → Import → Blogger. For WordPress versions 2.0.2 to 2.6.5, go to Manage → Import → Blogger. Or go to http://code.google.com/p/google-blog-converters-appengine/

Answer (score 0):

I've used this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-blogger-to-wp-converter/
It's a paid plugin, but the guys behind this one know their job well.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the developers of that plugin? If so, you should disclose it.